Is it possible to create a keymapping that imports the only choice for an undefined word, otherwise shows a list?
In IntelliJ IDEA, hitting Option+Enter over an undefined term would import the only choice if there was only one, otherwise would bring up a list of choices. Currently using LSP and Telescope, I have ga mapped to code actions, among which are 1 or more import choices (and others). Is it possible to make it work more like IntelliJ, e.g. where say gm maps to import-the-only-choice or else show all possible imports? If the latter part is difficult, it would also be okay to simply show the full list of code actions if more than one import is possible.
